# -moz-available height not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, mozilla

i use fill available in chrome and it's working perfectly but not in firefox.
here's the fiddle : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zv7fbscg/1/)
why does it not working? please help.

```
.container {
    background: steelblue;
    height: 100%;
    height: -moz-available;          /* WebKit-based browsers will ignore this. */
    height: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Mozilla-based browsers will ignore this. */
    height: fill-available;
    width: 100%;
    width: -moz-available;          /* WebKit-based browsers will ignore this. */
    width: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Mozilla-based browsers will ignore this. */
    width: fill-available;
}
```

Comment: Firefox sees `height: -moz-fill-available;` as invalid property. It only understands `-moz-available`. It's not recommended to use experimental CSS property as the functionality will change from time to time. Why don't use you traditional `html, body { height: 100%; }` trick?

Comment: i change it to `-moz-available` but it's still not working. the traditional way is working perfectly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for firefox you must set height:'100%' for body and html elements as follows:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: -moz-available; /* WebKit-based browsers will ignore this. */
    min-height: -webkit-fill-available; /* Mozilla-based browsers will ignore this. */
    min-height: fill-available;
}
```

this worked for me. I hope this can help you.

Comment: I had to use `min-height: -moz-available` and attach to the container (not a class), `height: 100%`

Comment: Also note, this _has_ to be %. vh does _not_ work here.